# Content Type User Permissions

Tags: 8, nodes

Is there a way to change the user permissions of a content type? As I would not like the anonymous user to access a specific content type.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module. All you'd have to do is:

- Create 1 group (pick your name) in 1 group type (pick your name).
- Give access to all users to that group.
- Use the group permissions to indicate you do NOT want to give anonymous users access to the content type you have in mind.

Done.